# Which linguistics professors, with a PhD in linguistics, have written on how they personally acquired second languages?

Tags: reference-request, l2-acquisition

Please recommend books or publications by

1. legitimate linguistics professors (anyone with a teaching position), at an accredited university
2. with a PhD in linguistics

detailing their own [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-language_acquisition) process. How did they learn — for themself and on their own —  new **L2 languages as an adult, after earning their PhD in linguistics**?

I'm not referring to L1 acquisition.

Linguistics S.E. closed [a similar question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/11688).

Comment: @Tommi **I meant "anyone in a university teaching position (the US use of the word)".** NOT <s>"only the permanent university faculty of the highest rank?"</s>

Comment: @Tsundoku the title fells too lengthy without any punctuation. hope my commas are OK?

Comment: Linguistics professors are more into research and theory of languages. They don't necessarily learn languages themselves in order to get to fluency, nor are they that likely to have developed some kind of great learning or self-teaching program. You probably want to look for foreign language professors, not linguistics professors.

Comment: I'm trying to decide if posting about J. Marvin Brown would be appropriate. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW8M4Js4UBA and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Marvin_Brown and https://beyondlanguagelearning.com/

Comment: @AML - thanks for the links, fascinating